# Form submission ignoring url option

Tags: extjs, modx

I'm trying to submit an ExtJs form the standard way, but the form is always submitting to the same page am not sure why although the url config option is correctly set

```
Players.panel.Subscription = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.apply(config,{
        id : 'players-subscription-home'
        ,border: false
        ,baseCls: 'modx-formpanel'
        ,standardSubmit: true
        ,baseParams: { action: 'mgr/player/getSubscribers' }
        ,url: Players.config.connectorUrl
        ,buttons: [{
            text: 'Export Subscribers'
            ,type: 'submit'
            ,handler:  function(){
                var fp = this.ownerCt.ownerCt,
                    form = fp.getForm();
                alert(fp.url);
                if (form.isValid()) {
                    // check if there are baseParams and if
                    // hiddent items have been added already
                    if (fp.baseParams && !fp.paramsAdded) {
                        // add hidden items for all baseParams
                        for (i in fp.baseParams) {
                            fp.add({
                                xtype: 'hidden',
                                name: i,
                                value: fp.baseParams[i]
                            });
                        }
                        fp.doLayout();
                        // set a custom flag to prevent re-adding
                        fp.paramsAdded = true;
                    }
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
        }]
    });
    Players.panel.Subscription.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
};

Ext.extend(Players.panel.Subscription,MODx.FormPanel);
Ext.reg('players-subscription-home',Players.panel.Subscription);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would troubleshoot by replacing this line with a hardcoded URL that you think is being set:
 Players.config.connectorUrl

Then see if you are still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: yup did that in the alert(fp.url), i'm getting the path to the right connector "/assets/components/players/connector.php"

Comment: Use Firefox to see where the form submits, its using Ajax submit (which is standard).

Comment: not really, i'm using the standard submit standardSubmit: true, which makes a normal post, it posts to the same page i'm on it

Comment: is there a fileUpload field in the form?